# importing openerp translation

Tags: odoo

I wanted to ask if there is any good way to import many translation files to openerp server? I know I can import one file at a time by using administration menu. But that would take a lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hello I do understand your concern that is take lot of time and hang ui.

If you are technical Persona then look for the Server Parameter for Internationalization

### [OpenERP Internationalisation options](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/01_getting_started.html#internationalization-options) :

```
    Use these options to translate OpenERP to another language.See i18n
    section of the user manual. Option '-d' is mandatory.Option '-l' is
    mandatory in case of importation

    --load-language=LOAD_LANGUAGE
                        specifies the languages for the translations you want
                        to be loaded
    -l LANGUAGE, --language=LANGUAGE
                        specify the language of the translation file. Use it
                        with --i18n-export or --i18n-import
    --i18n-export=TRANSLATE_OUT
                        export all sentences to be translated to a CSV file, a
                        PO file or a TGZ archive and exit
    --i18n-import=TRANSLATE_IN
                        import a CSV or a PO file with translations and exit.
                        The '-l' option is required.
    --i18n-overwrite    overwrites existing translation terms on updating a
                        module or importing a CSV or a PO file.
    --modules=TRANSLATE_MODULES
                        specify modules to export. Use in combination with
                        --i18n-export
```

Hope this will fix your Point.

Comment: Where should I use these options? Should I access some file from openerp server first? Simply using on terminal, doesn't do anything. Or I have to use it on postgresql? Thanks

Comment: when you start your server you have use this prams like
`$ ./openerp-server --addons=addons,web/addons --load=web -d db_name -l <langcode> --i18n-import=../../../de.po`